# Is it only the symetric matrix that have an ortonormal base with its eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

There is a question on an old exam that asks:

"Does it exist a base in $\mathbb{R^3}$, that consists of orthogonal eigenvectors of T. Explain your answer"

$T= \begin{bmatrix}-11&9&6\\-8&6&2\\ -6&6&7\end{bmatrix}$

Ive found all the eigenvectors and values but Im thinking because its not symetric, then there exist no such base. Is that correct, and why if so?

Answer (score 3):

You're right. Because $T$ is not symmetric, it does not have an orthonormal base of eigenvectors. This is guaranteed by the spectral theorem for symmetric matrices, so you can reach this conclusion simply by noting that $T$ is not symmetric.

If you correctly compute the eigenvalues, you should find that $T$ has real eigenvalues $3,-2,1$. However, no pair of associated eigenvectors is orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

> Ive found all the eigenvectors and values but Im thinking because its not symetric, then there exist no such base. Is that correct, and why if so?

It is a base. To prove it you just need to prove that the vectors of the base are linear independent. That is done calculating the rank of the Eigenvector matrix. If it has full rank then it's a base in this case for $\mathbb{R^3}$

$rank(T) = 3$(full rank) and $Det(T)\neq 0$ so $T$ is also invertible therefore the matrix $A$ is diagonizable.

For proving the orthogonality of the basis,take the dot product of the vectors and it should be zero for any two different vectors.

Comment: HI, sorry, forgot to put in the most important thing, they have to be orthogonal, ive now edited my post sorry for this!

Comment: There is a theorem that says "if a matrix is symmetric then it is diagonalizable" (there exist a basis for the vector space consisting of its eigenvectors).  The **converse**, that if there exist a basis consisting of its eigenvectors then the matrix is symmetric, is not true.

Comment: So if its symmetric then and ONLY then it is diagonalizable? And does that mean then and only then there exist a ortonormal basis to T?

Comment: A symmetric matrix has real eigenvalues, is always diagonalizable and has orthogonal eigenvectors. Thus the eigenvectors will form an orthogonal basis.

Comment: Existence of a orthonormal eigenbasis implies the operator is self adjoint, if you are working on a real inner product space. So yes there is no such base. The spectral theorem has a matrix version, I suppose.

Comment: @LiChunMin alright! Just for clarification because im not english native, what is a "self adjoint" matrix?

Comment: well I am not an English native too. To me self adjoint is just a math vocabulary that has a long definition. It says if V is an inner product space, T:V $\rightarrow$ V is self-adjoint if for any u, v in V,$\langle T(u), v \rangle = \langle u, T(v) \rangle$. These guys are similar to  symmetric matrices. But I think this is too far for you to go if you haven’t learnt about this before…just take the matrix version of spectral theorem as granted and read another textbook like Friedberg if you are really interested.

Comment: @user247327 that is incorrect

Comment: There are so many things that are wrong with this answer. The rank and determinant of $T$ have nothing to do with diagonalizability. If you actually computed the eigenvectors, you would fine that they are not orthogonal.

Comment: Just some clarifications, the theorem "a matrix is symmetric iff it is orthogonally diagonalizable" is only true when you restrict the entries to be real. It is not true if you allow complex numbers. The complex version of this theorem is:"a matrix is normal iff it is orthogonally diagonalizable". Try to play with A = [1,1;1,-1] with the complex dot product. It is also not true that if a matrix is diagonalizable then there is a orthogonal eigenbasis :)

Comment: I didn't look at the answer carefully. I just directly headed to the bottom and answer the question from the OP. I think I have to agree with Omnomnomnom that there are a few mistakes with this answer.